# SQL Alchemy - Deferring Multiple Groups

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to un-defer multiple groups in a sql alchemy query. Some of the columns I want aren't coming through once I include another group to un-defer. Both groups work when I un-defer individually--but it appears the second group is being read and not the first. Does anyone know if it's possible to un-defer multiple groups in sql alchemy? (code below)

Many thanks!

```
query = session.query(StudentAnswer, School, Student, CCStandard, Teacher, Period).\
        join(YearCycle, School, Student, Teacher, CCStandard, Period).\
        filter(and_(YearCycle.CalendarYear == year,YearCycle.CalendarCycle == cycle,\
                    School.SchoolDistrict == district, Subject.Code == subject, \
                    StudentAnswer.GradeLevelKey == grade)).\
        options(Load(Student).undefer_group('student_demographic'),(Load(Student).undefer_group('student_summative')))           
return query
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok if there are no takers....my workaround was to create two separate data frames by having two of the same queries with one of each group being undeferred. I merged them on a consistent column and I'm moving on with my life :)

Answer (score 0):

I've code that works for me along the lines of the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import undefer_group
...
options(undefer_group('contents'), undefer_group('prev_contents'))
```

No need for the `Load(Student)` part